# Does Device Farm supports python 3.5 and appium 1.6.4-beta?

Tags: ios, automation, python-3.5, aws-device-farm

I want to use `Device Farm` for ios testing but currently we are using `Python 3.5` and `Appium 1.6.4-beta`. As per their documentation, they only support `python 2.7` and I feel like this is not updated. Can anyone confirm if the device farm currently supports `python 3.5` and `appium 1.6.4-beta` ? I couldn't find this answer from their forum.

Documentation for device farm - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-python.html

> Version Information
>
> Currently, Device Farm supports Appium versions 1.6.3 and 1.4.16 and
>   Python version 2.7.6 (pip version 1.5.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team. The documentation is correct in that we only support Python 2.7 and Appium versions 1.4.16 and 1.6.3.

Comment: I am getting an error `No suites found to execute` when I run my tests in device farm. Can I message you regarding this ?

Comment: Sure. Feel free to PM me a run URL so we can take a look.

Comment: https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/home?region=us-west-2#/projects/cd30adfd-f958-437c-ab2d-cc5754bdb3fc/runs/4bb4ddfa-f7d3-4e85-bde0-dfb92e93426d/jobs/00000

Comment: I ma not able to understand the issue, could you please elaborate what's happening ?

Comment: Looks like there's missing dependencies in your zip file. Specifically, an ImportError for a module called "ros". I recommend creating a virtualenv, using the virtualenv's pip binary to install the dependencies from requirements.txt, and then running virtualenv's py.test --collect-only to catch any additional issues.

Comment: Could you share what's wrong with this test https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/home?region=us-west-2#/projects/cd30adfd-f958-437c-ab2d-cc5754bdb3fc/runs/79b638fb-8ddb-4ece-8a83-0fed68abd317/jobs/00000

Comment: It's incredibly frustrating that there is no error log in device farm for appium tests

Comment: any plan to support 1.6.4? because right now xcuitest on newer ios device need at least 1.6.4