# AWS Device Farm python3 support

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-device-farm

Does AWS DF supports python 3x for Appium python tests? 
Tried to run python3 tests, but it uses python2.7.

Comment: based on this [article](https://medium.com/@prabhath337/testing-android-applications-on-aws-device-farm-using-python-bc87859eb455) - yes. it is do support 3.0 and higher versions of python.

Comment: Tried to do as on this article, but it uses python2.7 in logs. Also AWS says that it support only python2.7 [link] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-python.html)

Comment: Have you did `python3 -m venv .venv` ? ( article assume you know the difference ) and so on? ( aws docs ARE always clear. Especially ones that 2 years old /s  )

Comment: @Butuzov good joke ;D

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-python.html) and an old answer from someone that works at aws it only supports 2.7
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056727/45598

Don't think anything changed yet, my tests only work with 2.7

Comment: We used for tests saucelabs. 
Anyway, I guess, that AWS something doing with that, python2.7 is deprecated.